# Failed recurring Membership payment

Tags: civimember

In the case of a monthly membership which is tied to a recurring monthly CC payment, if the payment fails once, there is no way to reuse the same recurring payment for the membership.
The only solution I have is to cancel the existing recurring payment and renew the membership and reenter the CC. Is there a better way?

The other issue is that I can only enter a new membership from today so if I am doing this 10 days after the membership payment was due, I either lose 10 days of revenue or I have to issue an invoice for the missing 10 days which is not ideal.

Looking for a workaround that helps avoid these issues or an extension that solves them... Any ideas?